# How to Skip Folders while looping through a directory?

Tags: python

I am writing a program that sorts files in a folder and each time I run the program it sort both files in the target folder and files inside folders in the target folder.

I want the program to loop through a folder that contains folders and files and skip folders and work on files instead.

For Clarity:
Folder A (Root folder) contains:

1. files
2. folders(B)

I want to loop through A while ignoring all folders(B) in A, I want my program to sort run the rest of the code.

This is my code:

```
import os
import shutil
import sys


def sortDirectory(directory, func=shutil.copy):

    if not os.path.isdir(directory):
        return 1

    
    
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):

            
        for file in files:

            name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
            ext = ext[1:]

            if not os.path.exists(os.path.join("out", ext)):
                os.makedirs(os.path.join("out", ext))

            if os.path.exists(os.path.join("out", ext, file)):
                count = 1
                for newFile in os.listdir(os.path.join("out", ext, '')):
                    if name == "_".join(newFile.split('.')[0].split('_')[:-1]):
                        count += 1
                outfile = name+'_'+str(count)+'.'+ext
            else:
                outfile = file
            print('File:', os.path.join(root, file),
                  '->', os.path.join("out", ext, outfile))
            func(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join("out", ext, outfile))

    return 0


def main():

    functionDict = {
        'm': shutil.move,
        'c': shutil.copy,
    }
    flag = shutil.copy
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        if sys.argv[2].lower()[0] in functionDict:
            flag = functionDict[sys.argv[2].lower()[0]]
        else:
            print("Unsupported 3rd argument. Use 'm'ove or 'c'opy")
            return 1

    elif len(sys.argv) == 1 or len(sys.argv) > 3:
        print(
            "Wrong amount of arguments. Only 2 arguments supported: [path function]")
        return 1

    return sortDirectory(sys.argv[1], flag)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: So do you want to process files inside the folders or not? It is unclear from the question: Only look at files in the folder A, or also at files in folder A -> B?

Comment: I want to only look at files in A and Skip all folder in A. @ypnos

Answer (score 1):

The function `os.walk()` is for recursive traversal, which is not what you need. You could use `os.listdir()` instead.

I also suggest to use the more modern and easy to use [pathlib interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

Example code:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def sortDirectory(directory, func=shutil.copy):
    root = Path(directory)
    if not root.is_dir():
        return 1

    for entry in root.iterdir():
        if not entry.is_file():
            continue
        name = entry.stem
        ext = entry.suffix[1:]

        (Path("out") / ext).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

        if (Path("out") / ext / entry.name).exists():
            # and so on
```

Comment: I ran into a TypeError on the ```Path("out" / ext).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)``` Line.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The operator `/` only works on Path objects, and as I had it before, at that point it was applied on a string.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also write `Path("out/ext")`, it is just not as clean.